# Why does compiler complaint about the path which can be statically ruled out (see code below)?

Tags: c++11, templates

For the following code, the compiler complaints that `no known conversion from 'const char *' to 'int' for 1st argument`. Compiler should know that `t` is an `int` while calling `g`. Therefore for `f("a")`, `g` won't be called.

Is there a good way to handle this without template overloading?

```
void g(int i) {
  cout << i << endl;
}

template <typename T>
void f(T t) {
  if (is_same<T, int>::value) {
    g(t);
  }
}

int main() {
        f("a");
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Dead code elimination is an *optimisation*, not a language feature.

In C++17 we get `if constexpr` which does what you want this to. As you have tagged C++11, I will assume you can't use that, and the sensible options are specialising your template or tag dispatching.

Explicit specialisation

```
template <typename T>
void f(T t) { }

template <>
void f(int t) { g(t); }
```

Tag dispatch

```
namespace detail {
    template <typename T>
    f(T t, std::false_type) { }

    template <typename T>
    f(T t, std::true_type)
    {
        g(t);
    }
}

template <typename T>
f(T t) { detail::f(t, is_same<T, int>{}); }
```